# Can Ant ReplaceRegexp task fail if the match is not found?

Tags: java, ant

Ant's [Replace](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) task has a nice option called `failOnNoReplacements`. Is something like this supported by [ReplaceRegexp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the answer is no, that task does not have such an option.  For one thing it is not documented.

Secondly, if you browse the source, http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/ReplaceRegExp.java, you will see that there is no such attribute in the class.  It looks like the only exceptions thrown by the task are when it is invoked with invalid arguments.